# Why doesn't this integral for the divergence of this vector field need to be fully calculated?

Tags: integration, vectors, divergence-operator

I have a vector field $\vec v=(x^2+y^2+z^2)(x \hat x+y \hat y +z \hat z)$, and I need to computed the integral of $\Delta \cdot \vec v$ over the region $x^2+y^2+z^2 \le 25$. I see that $\vec v=r^2\vec r$ which is $\vec v=r^3 \hat r$. The way I tried to compute the integral was like this:

$$\int r^3\hat r \cdot d\vec a \ ; \ d\vec a = r^2sin(\phi )drd\theta d\phi  $$

$$\int_0^5 r^3 \hat r\cdot r^2sin(\phi)d\theta d\phi= \int_0^{{\pi\over 2}}d\theta\int_0^{{\pi\over 2}}sin(\phi)d\phi\int_0^5r^5dr$$

$$=\Big({\pi\over 2} \Big)\Big(1\Big)\Big({1\over 6}5^6\Big)\approx 1302\pi$$

This isn't right because the solution should be $12,500\pi$. However the worked out solution doesn't make much sense to me because it seems like there a lot of steps missing and there isn't an explanation for what was done:

$$\int \vec A \cdot d\vec a= \int \big(r^3 \hat r \big) \cdot d\vec a$$
$$=r^3 4 \pi r^2=4r^5 \pi = 4 \big(5^5 \big) \pi= 12,500 \pi$$
$$where \ \ r=\sqrt{25}=5$$

I don't understand this solution. Why wasn't there any integration?

Comment: Please review the [MathJax tutorial](https://goo.gl/OWv9nr). I think by now you should be familiar with commands like `\sin` and `\,dx`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to compute the integral of the divergence of $\mathbf{v}$ over a closed *volume* bounded by a sphere of radius 5. The [Divergence Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem)
states that such volumetric integral is equal to the outward flux of the vector field:
$$
   \int _{V}\left(\mathbf {\nabla } \cdot \mathbf {v} \right)\,dV= \oint_S  (\mathbf {v} \cdot \mathbf {n} )\,dS. 
$$

As the vector field norm depends only on the radius and it is always normal to the sphere, $\mathbf{v}\cdot\mathbf{n}$ is constant over the sphere and equal to $r^3=125$. Then
$$
\oint_S  (\mathbf {v} \cdot \mathbf {n} )\,dS=125\oint dS=125\cdot 4\pi r^2=12,500\pi.
$$
There was integration, but the *symmetries* of the problem made the computation very easy.

In practice, you tried to compute the volume integral of the vector field, not its divergence, and you equated a *vector* area element $d\mathbf{a}$ with a *volume* element $ r^{2}\sin \theta \,\mathrm {d} r\,\mathrm {d} \theta \,\mathrm {d} \varphi$, obtaining a incorrect result.